# How to directly download a file using remote machine node browser to my hub machine(where my project code workspace is present) using selenium grid?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have a testcase written in selenium(I am using autoIt for handling file download window of browser) where my code is on hub machine and the remote node browser handles a download. Now I want the downloaded file in my code workspace folder named 'output' which is on hub machine. Is that possible? If yes how?

Comment: can you please explain in more detail what is where and what you mean by "node browser"

Answer (score 2):

Instead, I'd recommend having a server that holds all downloaded files.  Since it would be very difficult and very time consuming to come up with a solution to figure out how to save a file from the nodes to the hub's file system, why not have a web service?

Something like this -

```
performTest();
downloadFile();

void downloadFile() {
  url = "myhub:2000/upload"
  post(url, driver.getUrl())
}
```